# How does the same electron orbit both atoms in covalent bond?

Tags: electrons, atoms, covalent-compounds, carbon-family

During elementary school chemistry, when they teach about the covalent bond, they say that both atoms need the electron but they can't lose or gain them so they share it.

And for instance they show us the Lewis dot structure to clarify how do they share an electron.

If we move further into the question about how electrons actually get shared among two atoms, then we learn about orbitals, overlapping, sigma bond, pi bond etc.

But the actual question remains unsatisfied...

They say that the orbitals of two atoms overlap each other and that the electron will move there, but how?

How can the same electron that is shared in a covalent bond orbit nucleons of both atoms simultaneously? How is it actually shared between atoms? And what will be the path of its trajectory around two atoms?

Comment: The electron does not orbit both nuclei, it envelops them.

Comment: Even If electrons do "orbit" anything in there (like in Bohmian mechanics), such orbits are literally unknowable, so you're wasting your time. Just learn about orbitals.

Comment: @Mithoron Quite an unlucky term, this orbital, isn't it?

Comment: @Poutnik Kinda yeah, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good analogue to the puzzle of how an electron in a molecule (say in the $\ce{H2+}$ cation) can be "shared" between two nuclei is a [circumbinary planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumbinary_planet). This gravitational equivalent involves a planet orbiting a binary star system. The planet moves along a trajectory about the center of mass of the two stars. Kinetic energy keeps the various bodies from crashing into each other, while centripetal force due to the mutual gravitational attraction keeps them in orbit. It should be possible to construct an even closer analogue involving electrostatic charges, a set of charged spheres, say, where two are positively charged and the third negatively.

While a classical analogue misses important details regarding the *delocalized* distribution of an electron in a molecule, something that requires quantum mechanics, it explains how it is possible for one particle to move in the basin of two attractors. One important difference with the gravitational example is that in that case all of the bodies attract, whereas in the molecule the electron functions as a sort of "glue" that keeps the nuclei, which otherwise repel, from flying away from each other.

> How can the same electron that is shared in a covalent bond orbit nucleons of both atoms simultaneously?

The above suggests how a body can be in orbit about two others. It is important to add that a covalent bond is a fiction created to simplify the representation of molecular structures in  a form that is understandable to humans (and presumably a form that can be conveyed visually). As a concept it implies that the electron is "shared", yes, in the sense that the electron is trapped in a stable arrangement due to mutual attraction to the two nuclei, and that due to the attraction the electron can be said to be found with a high probability in the region between the nuclei. That high density between the nuclei is what we like to call a covalent bond.

> How is it actually shared between atoms? And what will be the path of its trajectory around two atoms?

The electron doesn't really belong to either atom, in the same way that Earth does not belong to the Sun (well, it is trapped by the gravitational pull of the Sun within the solar system). The electron is doing what electrons do, which is "spread itself out" about the atoms due to wavelike properties while remaining bound to the nuclei due to electrostatic attraction. It helps to think of an electron as a fuzzy (probability) cloud rather than a concrete particle.

Comment: The circumbinary planet analogy is not really accurate fo two reasons. First, in the planetary case the orbiter would have to be far away compared with the dustance between the parent bodies to make the orbit stable. This works with gravity but does not do so well for chemical bonding. Second, as noted elsewhere we don't really have orbital motion. Enveloping is more accurate.

Comment: @OscarLanzi I agree that there is no ideal classical analogue to chemical bonding, but a circumbinary system with a planet in stable orbit about two as opposed to a single star provides a starting point to grasp how attractive forces can lead to this shared orbital distribution. Note the analogy works in the classical sense that F=ma, such that the planet (or electron) moves much more quickly than the more massive body or particle.

Comment: There are at least two basic reasons it is a flawed analogue and I attempt to address these later in my answer. Maybe I downplay the importance of the differences but I am trying to convince the OP that a shared orbit is not so mysterious.

Answer (score 2):

An electron doesn't have a trajectory, a path. The electron is not a small planet turning around the nucleus-sun. The electron has no speed, no position. If it had a velocity anywhere, it would progressively loose energy by synchrotron radiation, and it will slowly crash down on the nucleus. The electron has no speed, and this does not mean that its speed is zero. No ! It does not have any speed at all, as it does not have any religion. The electron is only described by a wave function. And this wave function can cover or envelop one atom of course, but it may also cover or envelop two or more atoms in covalent bonds.

Comment: Can't help but wonder how you'd explain relativistic effects with your "no speed".  Not to mention particle/wave duality.

Comment: I can't visualise/imagine what does it acutally mean by enveloping atoms

Comment: @Yug Ahuja. An electron has no dimension, but it looks as is it is about as big as the atom. Its probability of presence goes to zero when the distance to the nucleus tends to infinite. If it had only two dimensions, it would be like a thick three-dimensional tissue becoming infinitely thin at large distances from the nucleus. It is not possible to represent it at three dimensions.

Comment: @Mithoron I have objected to this Maurice's view too on a related post. Considering Dirac himself was evaluating electron speed is (at least for light atoms) much slower than c and therefore SR (speed-wise) corrections to a wave equation is negligible. Hard to imagine Dirac is not qualified for statements in quantum mechanics.

Comment: @Poutnik. Dirac is right. And Pekka Pykkö also. They are able to calculate, but they are unable to explain the relativistic correction to electrons in atoms having no speed. .

Comment: @Mithoron. I am afraid I cannot explain relativistic effects with the model of no speed. But if you read Pekka Pykkö's article about relativistic effect in chemistry, you will soon read that they do not have a simple way of explaining that an electron has no speed, but can have a relativistic contraction when the electron is moving nearly at the velocity of the light. I agree that it is contradictory. Ref. : Pekka Pykkö, Relativity and the Periodic System of Elements, Accounts of Chemical Research, Vol. 12, No. 8, (1979), p. 276 - 281.

Comment: No speed? I've taken an electron out for a spin and they get around an atom in no time at all. ;-)

Comment: Can't you define a speed as the momentum divided by the mass, at least in absolute value terms, if not vectorially?

Comment: @Buck Thorn. The idea of defining the speed as the momentum divided by the mass is a good idea. Thank you for the idea.

Comment: I should add: the expectation value of the *velocity* (not the speed!) of an electron bound in an atom is zero, since it is confined to the atom and has zero average velocity in the reference frame of the atom. You might say the same of the Earth averaged over the reference frame of the solar system (I think). Otherwise it would escape.